# Entrust Certificate Explorer is missing on Win 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7, certificate

So I wanted to import a certificate to my Win 7 SP1 PC, but the Entrust Certificate Explorer isn't showing up when I search for it. So I looked in the directory and under installed programs, but in both cases its not there. Any idea where it can be or where I can get it, because I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilize an MMC on the local machine:

> **Managing trusted root certificates for a local computer**
>
> 1. Click `Start`, click `Start Search`, type `mmc`, and then press `Enter`.
> 2. On the `File` menu, click `Add/Remove Snap-in`.
> 3. Under `Available snap-ins`, click `Local Group Policy Object Editor`,click `Add`, select the computer whose local Group Policy
>      object (GPO) you want to edit, and then click `Finish`.
> 4. If you have no more snap-ins to add to the console, click `OK`.
> 5. In the console tree, go to `Local Computer Policy`, `Computer Configuration`, `Windows Settings`, `Security Settings`, and then
>      click `Public Key Policies`.
> 6. Double-click `Certificate Path Validation Settings`,and then click the `Stores` tab.
> 7. Select the `Define these policy settings` check box.
> 8. Under `Per user certificate stores`, clear the `Allow user trusted root CAs to be used to validate certificates` and `Allow users to
>      trust peer trust certificates` check boxes.
> 9. Under `Root certificate stores`, select the root CAs that the client computers can trust, and then click `OK` to apply the new
>      settings.
>
> **Adding certificates to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store for a local computer**
>
> 1. Click `Start`, click `Start Search`, type `mmc`, and then press `Enter`.
> 2. On the `File` menu, click `Add/Remove Snap-in`.
> 3. Under `Available snap-ins`, click `Certificates`,and then click `Add`.
> 4. Under `This snap-in will always manage certificates for`, click `Computer account`, and then click `Next`.
> 5. Click `Local computer`, and click `Finish`.
> 6. If you have no more snap-ins to add to the console, click `OK`.
> 7. In the console tree, double-click `Certificates`.
> 8. Right-click the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` store.
> 9. Click `Import` to import the certificates and follow the steps in the Certificate Import Wizard.

(Source:  [Manage Trusted Root Certificates - Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx))

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: I appreciate  your help with that, @DavidPostill .  My apologies... I have previously read **all** of the articles within the Help Center.  Forgive my ignorance as a relatively new contributor, but after devoting a healthy amount of time & effort towards formatting the text (along with appropriate code block emphasis) and meticulously citing the source, I thought that the references were formatted rather well.  This wasn't simply a lack of effort or not really paying attention.

Comment: No problem. It wasn't meant as a telling off :)